# Incorrect error message in sign up django-allauth form

Tags: django, django-allauth

When sigh up in django-allauth with not unique email address showing error message under email input:

```
%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.
```

Why it's show it without appropriate model_name and field_label?

Comment: do you mean that it's rendering the message as it: %(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists. ? without replacing model_name and field_labels ?

Comment: It's a bug, follow [this issue](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1449).

Comment: Yes, it's not replasing %(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s

Comment: Thanks Kevin, It's help!